# Пагинация в модуле Yii2 Images

Tags: php, yii2, pagination

Добрый день, подскажите, возможно ли сделать пагинацию на основе той, что уже реализована в yii выводя картинки при помощи модуля Yii2 Images? Запрос в базу идет `$work = Work::findOne($id);`, то есть берется из бд одна запись, а в модуле уже формируется уже сам запрос и его никак не поменяешь, можно было бы сделать запрос на прямую, напрямую из таблицы image, но при выводе картинок их необходимо обрезать

Код модели

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
class Work extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'image' => [
                'class' => 'rico\yii2images\behaviors\ImageBehave',
            ]
        ];
    }
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'work_cat';
    }
}
```

Код контроллера

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\Work;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class WorkController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $works = Work::find()->all();
        return $this->render('index', compact('works'));
    }
    public function actionView()
    {
        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');

        $work = Work::findOne($id);
        return $this->render('view', compact('work'));
    }
}
```

Сам модуль - https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images

Comment: Добрый день.Информации очень мало, чтобы дать ответ. Дополните свой вопрос кодом. Какой именно модуль? Если Вы получаете одну запись из базы, то что Вы хотите выводить ? Изображения? Разбить вывод изображений на страницы?

Comment: Дополнил информацию, при таком запросе `$work = Work::findOne($id);` а сам модуль уже добавляет запрос `SELECT * FROM 'image' WHERE ('itemId'=1) AND ('modelName'='Work') ORDER BY 'isMain' DESC, 'id'`

Comment: Но всё равно не ясно, что обрезать и для чего пагинация? Что именно Вас смущает в запросе, который отправляет виджет?

Comment: Если будет добавлено много фотографий, то без пагинации страница будет загружаться долго, в самом модуле как я понял не предусмотрена пагинация и если выводить без помоги модуля, то картинки нужно будет обрезать при загрузки( в модуле можно при выводе с помощью функции), а модуль записывает в таблицу уже запись вида `Works/Work6/b21178.jpg`

Comment: Модуль прикрепляет к модели какие-то изображения? Правильно я понял? Изображения к определённой модели. Настройте связь между моделью и изображениями и получайте всё одним запросом вместе с пагинацией.

Comment: Да, модуль прикрепляет к модели изображения, на основе запроса, автоматически формируется запрос и как я понимаю настроить связь возможно только в самом модуле

Comment: Настроить связь в модели, к которой относятся изображения. И модуль не очень-то нужен будет. Если, конечно, Вы его используете только ради вывода изображений.

Comment: Нет, он используется для мультизагрузки, вывода главной фотографии, обрезания и сжатия картинок. Если без модуля, то возникает проблема с обрезанием фотографий

Comment: 'isMain'  это обозначает главную фотографию?

Comment: Да, с этим проблем нет, только с постраничным выводом картинок через этот модуль

Comment: Зачем тогда модуль для вывода изображений? Создайте связь между моделью Work и моделью изображений. Делайте один запрос и в этом запросе получайте связанные изображения. Тогда будет проще настроить постраничную навигацию для изображений.

Comment: Как тогда быть с обрезанием фотографий?

Comment: При загрузке делайте всё, что Вам надо с фотографиями, а выводите через связь уже обработанные изображения.

Comment: В таблицу через модуль добавляется не название фото, а путь `Works/Work4/d50025.jpg`

Comment: Правильно, путь к изображениям. Сами изображения куда сохраняются? Вот надо сохранять уже обработанные изображения в директорию, путь к этим изображениям в базу. И через связь получаете путь к изображению и выводите его.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте через dataProvider, в нем есть стандартная пагинация. $model->getImages() возвращает ActiveQuery или массив объектов? 
Можно отнаследоваться от ImageBehavior, переопределить метод getImages() чтобы возвращал  ActiveQuery, и использовать ActiveDataProvider. Или использовать ArrayDataProvider
Во view данные в linkPager передавайте 'pagination'=>$dataProvider->getPagination()